# Multidimensional array initialization in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm reading "Sams Teach Yourself C++ in One Hour a Day" and get stuck with "Lesson 4". It says that I can initialize all elements of multidimensional array with the following code:

```
int x[n][m] = {1};
```

But as I understand it's wrong. This code creates array with only one element (x[0][0]) equals 1. Is it a mistake in the book or what?

Comment: Can you provide a direct quote just to make sure you didn't misunderstand it?

Comment: Show the definition of `n` and `m`.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a better [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Although books like that might be a better fit for your learning style, having a solid [reference](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) is not optional. C++ is an unforgiving language so it's important to have a manual that you can consult tha explains things in depth, not just superficially.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, this declaration will indeed initialize *all* elements of the array. However, only element `x[0][0]` will get initialized to `1`. The remaining elements (if any) will get initialized to `0`.

So, formally the book is right (if you quoted it correctly). You simply misinterpreted what it said.

Comment: @tadman: It certainly does :) However, the OP's wording seems to suggest that there are other elements in the array.

Comment: Certainly! Any C++ book that spends a lot of time talking about C arrays, though, is immediately suspect.

Comment: Thanks for answer:) So this behavior only works if you specify zero?

Comment: @Lev Zakharov: Not sure what you mean by "works". If you want to initialize all elements to the same value, then yes, it only works for zero. Otherwise, it works as I described above. In C++ you can simply say `int x[n][m] = {}` or `int x[n][m]{}` to zero-out everything.

Comment: I'm not certain the remaining elements are initialized to 0. Their values are undefined, aren't they?

Comment: @AnT The book says: "Initializing all elements to zero could not be any simpler...". So I assumed that this rule applies to other values.

Comment: @tadman: That's false. C++, just like C, follows the "All-Or-Nothing" principle in aggregate initialization. When you supply explicit initializer for just a portion of the aggregate, the rest invariably gets default-initialized for you. In C the `= { 0 }` initializer is well-known as a universal/idiomatic way to zero-initialize anything.

Comment: @ant Thanks for clarifying.